# HTML email outlook issue with the width, Content is wider than table

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have the below HTML email however the content keeps breaking out of the tables in outlook, I cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong...

The whole email should be 600px wide

Here is my code:

```
        <html>

        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>pescado</title>
        </head>
        <style>
            body{background-color: #dfe0e2;}
        </style>
        <body bgcolor="#dfe0e2">
            <div style="width:600; margin:0 auto;">
            <table border="0" width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr><td width="600">    <div style="padding:10px 0px 5px 8px;color:black;font:11px arial,helvetica; text-align:center">Can&rsquo;t see this? <a style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank" href="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/IT-Systems-offer1.htm"><span style="color:black">Please click here to see it in your browser</span></a></div>
                </td></tr>
            </table>
            <table border="0" width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="268" bgcolor="#404852"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.pescado.co.uk/"><img style="width:268px; height:85px;display: block; border:0px" src="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/logo.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#404852">
                    <div style="text-align: right; color:#fff; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; padding-right:23px;">Call us today<br><span  style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fe5a04;; font-size: 27px;">033 000 22 000</span></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4"><img src="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/it-system4.jpg" alt="Is your IT system making you this happy?" style="width:603px; height:364px;display: block; border:0px" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#667882"><p align="center" style="padding:23px 23px 22px 23px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;"><font face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF">Pescado offers an intelligent approach to IT service and planning. Let’s talk, an audit costs nothing and as part of the service you can have the first month for free, no questions asked.</font></p></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="http://www.pescado.co.uk/yes-please-offer-1/" target="_blank" style="border: none;"><img src="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/green-yes-IT.png" alt="" style="border: none;"/></a></td>
        <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="http://www.pescado.co.uk/no-to-trial/" target="_blank" style="border: none;"><img src="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/red-no-IT.png" alt="" style="border: none;"/></a></td>

                </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="600">
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;"><font face="Arial" text-align="center" color="#3e464f" font-size="16px" line-height="26px;">Pescado IT is part of the Pescado family, a voice and data specialist company. We supply IT, connectivity, office phone systems and business mobiles. Our approach is to ensure you can focus on running your business knowing the technology side is covered. Whether it’s a simple Office365 migration, a new PC purchase, data security and hacking prevention or data backups we‘ve got it covered. So go green and see what you can have if you talk to us.</font></p>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; colour:#fe5a04;"><font face="Arial" text-align="center" color="#fe5a04" font-size="16px" line-height="26px;">Office phone systems | Vodafone One Net | Business Mobiles <br>Connectivity | Hardware &amp; Software</font></p>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></td>
        </tr>





                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#32373b" width="600">

                    <div style="text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #fff;"> <br>
                    <br>
                  To take advantage of this offer contact us on:<br>
                    <span style="font-size: 33px; color: #fe5a04; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; line-height: 44px;">033 000 22 000</span>
                   </div>

                    <div style="text-align:center;  padding-left: 45px; padding-right: 45px;"><font color="#fff" style="font-size: 27px; text-transform: none; font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 28px; letter-spacing: -1px; color:#ffffff;">We look forward to speaking to you soon. 
                    </font>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" width="600">
                   <div style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;  padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><font color="#3e464f" style="font-size: 12px; text-transform: none; font-weight: normal; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; letter-spacing: -1px;">*Pescado will offer the IT service charges for support services free for 1 month of a 12 month agreement
        Pescado will offer 3 months free of charge line rental on any mobile connections brought from any other service provider. The 3 months line rental including any further bolt-ons at network level will be paid in full upon invoice at month 4 of a standard 24 month agreement or if the customer wishes can be spread over the term of the agreement Pescado will offer 3 months free of charge on any Pescado service applies to Pescado Ola phones systems, connectivity &amp; calls and lines packages. Pescado reserve the right to remove these offers at anytime.
                    </font>
                    </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>

          <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td width="44"><a href="https://twitter.com/PescadoGroup" target="_blank"><img style="width:35px; height:46px;display: block; border:0px" src="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/twitter-link.jpg" /></a></td>
                <td width="43"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/pescado" target="_blank"><img style="width:35px; height:46px;display: block; border:0px" src="http://www.pescado.co.uk/newsletter/linkedin-link.jpg" /></a></td>
                    <td width="246" bgcolor="#dfe0e2">

                    </td>
                </tr>       

            </table>


        </div>


        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: Email software is outdated and often doesn't render `CSS` so you should focus on doing almost everything in `HTML`. Nevertheless I'd try adding `px` to any `width` or `height` element declarations. The browser doesn't know what you mean by with `width:600`, 600 `em`? `px`? `%`?

Comment: On one of your images, you've got `<img style="width:603px;>`